# C# 6 bool and new null check with ? what to return back

Tags: c#

C# 6.0 code:

```
public bool HasLeaderOtherThanSelf
{
    return LeaderMembership?.AthleteId != App.CurrentAthlete.Id;
}
```

What is correct way to implement it in C# 4?

To return `null` or `false` back if `LeaderMembership` is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with extension

```
public static TValue GetOrDefault<TObject, TValue>(this TObject obj, Func<TObject, TValue> getter, TValue defaultValue = default(TValue))
            where TObject : class
        {
            return obj == null ? defaultValue : getter(obj);
        }
```

you can use it as:

```
public bool HasLeaderOtherThanSelf
{
    return LeaderMembership.GetOrDefault(x => x.AthleteId) != App.CurrentAthlete.Id;
}
```

or if you want to return null:

```
public static TValue? GetOrDefault<TObject, TValue>(this TObject obj, Func<TObject, TValue> getter, TValue? defaultValue = default(TValue?))
    where TObject : class
    where TValue : struct
{
    return obj == null ? defaultValue : getter(obj);
}
```

Comment: This assumes that an `Id` value of 0 is invalid. Your `GetOrDefault` method returns 0 for a null `obj`, which could be equal to the `CurrentAthlete.Id` otherwise.

Comment: @mbrc it has a subtle difference, in that the result is zero instead of null when `LeaderMembership` is null. If `CurrentAthlete.Id` can be zero, then you're testing `0 != 0` which is false, instead of `null != 0` which is true.

Comment: @Michael do you have any suggestion how to make method better? It must work correctly.

Answer (score 4):

In C# 4.0:

```
public bool HasLeaderOtherThanSelf
{
    return LeaderMembership != null && LeaderMembership.AthleteId != App.CurrentAthlete.Id;
}
```

OR

```
public bool? HasLeaderOtherThanSelf
{
   if(LeaderMembership == null)
   {
      return null;
   }
   return LeaderMembership.AthleteId != App.CurrentAthlete.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
public bool HasLeaderOtherThanSelf
{
    if(LeaderMembership != null)
       return LeaderMembership.AthleteId != App.CurrentAthlete.Id;
    return false;
}
```

Or if you want to be able to return `null` you should change your `HasLeaderOtherThanSelf` type to 
[`Nullable Bool`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/nullable-bool) (`bool?`):

```
public bool? HasLeaderOtherThanSelf
{
    if(LeaderMembership != null)
       return LeaderMembership.AthleteId != App.CurrentAthlete.Id;
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You would return `false` back.

```
public bool HasLeaderOtherThanSelf
{
    if (LeaderMembership != null)
       return LeaderMembership.AthleteId != App.CurrentAthlete.Id;
    return false;
}
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
public bool HasLeaderOtherThanSelf
{
    return LeaderMembership != null && LeaderMembership.AthleteId != App.CurrentAthlete.Id;
}
```

Comment: the first code will be compiled like the second code. i just thought its good to mention it. they will compile to same thing while the first code is more readable IMO

Answer (score 2):

If `LeaderMembership` is null, the result of `LeaderMembership?.AthleteId` will be a null value of type nullable int (assuming `AthleteId` is an integer).

Presumably the `App.CurrentAthlete.Id` is also an integer, so the comparison of a null value of type nullable int with an int will be false.

Answer (score 0):

Your C# 6 code translates to

```
public bool HasLeaderOtherThanSelf
{
    var leaderMembership = LeaderMembership;
    return (leaderMembership == null ? default(int?) : leaderMembership.AthleteId)
      != App.CurrentAthlete.Id;
}
```

Note that your code reads `LeaderMembership` only once, and to accurate emulate that in C# <6, you need an additional local variable.

Note if `LeaderMembership` is `null` and `App.CurrentAthlete.Id` is non-null, your existing code returns `true`, but most of the other answers return `false` for that case. `false` is probably a better answer, but not an accurate translation of your existing code.

Comment: compiler will optimize to read the property only once anyways. keep your code clean!

Comment: @SimpleVar No, the compiler won't do that. The runtime might, depending on what the property getter looks like, but if the property getter has a side effect, you will easily be able to determine that that side effect takes place twice if you read the property twice. Anyway, the question was how to rewrite specific C# 6 code in C# <6. Regardless of whether reading the property twice is acceptable, it would be a change in behaviour, it would not be a faithful rewrite to a previous language version.

Answer (score 0):

In `C# 4` it look like:

```
public bool HasLeaderOtherThanSelf
{
    return LeaderMembership != null && LeaderMembership?.AthleteId != App.CurrentAthlete.Id;
}
```

But use "hardcode" is not good practice) Will be better do something like this:

**First variant**:

```
public bool IsNullOrEquivalent<T>(T target, Func<T, bool> comparer)
        where T : class
{
    return target == null
        && comparer(target);
}
```

that you can use like:

```
var result = new NonExtensionComparer().IsNullOrEquivalent(LeaderMembership, e => e.AthleteId == App.CurrentAthlete.Id);
```

**Second varian (extension)**:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEquivalent<T>(this T target, Func<T, bool> comparer)
{
    return target == null
        && comparer(target);
}
```

use:

```
var result = LeaderMembership.IsNullOrEquivalent(e => e.AthleteId == App.CurrentAthlete.Id);
```